# What is the correct RegEx to extract my substring

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input string like this

```
$(xx.xx.xx)abcde$(yyy.yyy.yyy)fghijk$(zzz.zz.zz.zzz)
```

I want to be able to pull out each subset of strings matching $(anything inside here), so for the example above I would like to get 3 substrings.
the characters in between the brackets do not necessarily always match the same pattern.

I have tried using the following regex

```
(\$\([a-z]+.*\))
```

but this matches whole string, due to the fact it starts with '$', anything in middle, and ends with ')'

Hopefully this makes sense.
I should also note that I have very limited experience using regex.

Thanks

Comment: @AvinashRaj balance your parentheses after `OR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\$\([a-z]+.*?\))
```

Use `?` to make your search non greedy.`*` is greedy and consumes the max it can.adding `?` to `*` makes it non greedy and it will stop at the first instance of `)`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/28

Comment: works perfectly thanks. Marked as answer for clarity & identifying the problem exactly(greedy quantifier).
and for those also interested in the greedy quantifier have a look here http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap

Comment: @ljsg you're welcome.You can also use `(\$\([^)]+\))` which is better optimised :)

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
 \((.*?)\)\g
```

for the given string **$(xx.xx.xx)abcde$(yyy.yyy.yyy)fghijk$(zzz.zz.zz.zzz)** it returns the three substring..

```
MATCH 1
1.  [2-10]  `xx.xx.xx`
MATCH 2
1.  [18-29] `yyy.yyy.yyy`
MATCH 3
1.  [38-51] `zzz.zz.zz.zzz`
```

http://regex101.com/r/bX7qR2/1

Comment: What's the meaning of `\g`? And you forgot the leading `$`.

Comment: here `\g` mean Global search.. mean it will search given pattern in whole string till end of input.. else it will return after first match pattern.. if we don't use `\g` it will return only first possible match mean `xx.xx.xx`

Comment: In which flavor of regex? I've never seen that. I guess you want say `/g` but you've forgoten the delimiters.